# Get current directory path while adding queries

Tags: excel, vba

i've got a snippet that makes a query for file names in a directory. It works just fine, but this directory changes all the time and i have to manually update the source link in the code. I wonder if I could somehow incorporate ActiveWorkbook.path (or any other workaround) in this particular construction instead of retyping the pathway everytime i have to make a query in a new folder

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Stage 6", Formula:= _
    Source = Folder.Files(""C:\Users\Romanov\Desktop\TESTBOX\INDEX2"")
```

Comment: You definitely can concatenate it with `&`. Have you tried it and/or what problem(s) are you having doing this?

Comment: hi, could you give an example of how i can concatenate absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample showing how you could go about this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateFolderQueryFormula(ByVal psQueryName As String, ByVal psPath As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Queries(psQueryName).Formula = "let Source = Folder.Files(""" & psPath & """) in Source"
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    UpdateFolderQueryFormula "Stage 6", ThisWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

Call `UpdateFolderQueryFormula` whenever required, be it when the workbook opens,  or at the user's request, possibly with one or both parameters being supplied by the user (add validation and error handling, in this case).

When you assign to `.Formula`, you must supply a properly built string that will look just like the one created through Excel's user interface.

Comment: i tried that, but, unfortunately it didn't work out. Thanx for giving me a drift though, i'll try to think smth up this way

Comment: What exactly did not work out? Did you run into an error, and if so, what were the number & description?